# What's the meaning of "lapdog"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What's the meaning of lapdog in this context?

> Cablegate revealed that some countries cooperated with the U.S. more
>   than others, for example. Sweden played **lapdog**. Austria annoyed the
>   U.S. etc.

I looked up *lapdog* in the Longman dictionary but couldn't find it. Is it a newly coined word?

Comment: Dictionary.com has your answer: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lapdog

Comment: Likewise [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lapdog#Noun): "(derogatory) one who is completely obedient, unquestioning, and submissive to the government or another party" but it takes an [etymonline reference](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=lapdog&searchmode=none) to get 1950 date for that usage.

Comment: The OED doesn't list this meaning, only the literal one!

Comment: -1. Likewise [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lap_dog#Idiomatic_use) and [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=lapdog), which are the first two Google results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lap-dog is a dog small enough to sit on someone’s lap. It’s been around for more than 500 years. Used figuratively in your example, it suggests that Sweden is a small pet belonging to the United States and that it will not act aggressively against its owner.

Comment: It's the term that's been around, not the kind of dog, I suppose?

Comment: @Kris: The term could hardly exist without the dog. The OED’s earliest citation is from John Evelyn: ‘Those Lap-dogs had so in delicijs by the Ladies . . . are a pigmie sort of Spaniels.’

Comment: I mean, they could have been something and then came to be called lap-dogs much later owing to some reason.

Comment: @Kris: Who knows? A dictionary can only record words as they appear in surviving texts, at least before the twentieth century.

Comment: I found this on Wiki: Recent genetic study confirms that the Pekingese lapdog, bred in ancient China to fit inside the sleeves of a man's robe, is one of the oldest breeds of dog.

Comment: @Kris: Similarly, I suppose dachshunds existed long before they were called sausage dogs.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lap_dog#Idiomatic_use), this term means:

> The term lapdog is also used to describe a submissive person, such as a "yes" man, or an institution that can be very easily controlled

[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lapdog) has this definition:

> a person who attaches himself to someone in admiration

[M-W Learner's](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/search/lapdog) has this definition:

> a weak person who is controlled by someone else